# Connection time out error in java web application

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am developing an Java web application using Netbeans 7.0.1 and MySQL 5.0. I am using Apache Tomcat as server. My application works well when I run it on my own machine, but it gives me connection timed out error when try to access it from other machine using URL like `IPaddress:port/project/`. It gives me some error like:

1. connection has timed out
2. problem in loading page
3. please reload the page

I tried it with various browsers, but problem is same. I can't acecss my web appliaction from remote machine.

Comment: what is the jsp/servlet you are trying to call and what is the code there ?

Comment: 'Connection timed out' basically reads 'However I tried, I could not connect'. Looks much like a wrong IP address / port number problem. Take another look at your config. Use telnet to make sure you have a listening process on given host:port.

Comment: i made sure that port number and ip address are correct. but problem is not solved

Comment: @adesh : In Windows XP, i guess you simply go to windows firewall in your control panel, and then add this port to your exceptions list. I guess it's easy in XP. [Configuring Firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875357). Hope that might can help.  Regards

Comment: thank you  sir , hope it will solve my problem.. sir can i get your mail id . if i stuck with the same problem so that i can mail you my problems. sir,i am a student trying an web project. if you help me it will be very easy for me.

Comment: if turn the firewall off will it cause any undesired effect?

Comment: You can turn your firewall off, for the time being, when  you trying your effort on connecting, but do remember to switch it back on. Better stick to stackoverflow, this site is full of brilliant people. If i may not be able to help you, someone surely will. Please Do check my profile for the email. Regards

Comment: thank you... this site really rocks !!!!